# How can I authenticate a user to allow them to insert a record in my profile

Tags: authorization, mern, jwt

Im planning to make a MERN website with 2 accounts, patient and doctor accounts.However, in order for the doctor to put a record, the doctor should be logged in and can only insert a record when he is authorized by the patient. I have used 2 JWT token in an API for inserting a record, one for checking if the doctor is logged in and the other for knowing if he is authorized by that specific patient and it's working fine using postman because I manually placed the token. my problem is the token for authorizing the doctor, where should i saved it so that the doctor can use that token to insert a record. My last call is I'll just save it to the database of that doctor. is there a better way for this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of creating a second JWT, perhaps it would be better to note on the patient account which doctors are authorized to add records.

Comment: @displacedtexan , thank you, I followed your advice and it works now. Could you help me with my other problem? I posted it a while ago.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use JWT that much so I can't help out on your other problem. Good luck!